Boundary сonditions specified in different domains
I am modeling mass transport phenomena involving convection and diffusion within a two-dimensional box. The box has a height ranging from 0 to h along the y-axis and is divided into two domains along the x-axis: domain 1 from d0 to d1, and domain 2 from d1 to d2.
The boundary conditions are:
Where, C(t,x,y) is the concentration and C^* is a constant nominal concentration. I am trying to use the following script to solve this problem in Wolfram Mathematica version 13.2, however I don’t know how to write the boundary conditions at the y-axis. I have used functions such as Piecewise, DirichletCondition, If, and WhenEvent to specify the different domains within the condition but many errors appears and the system does not solve.
eqns=D[C[t,x,y],t]==Piecewise[{{dif1*D[C[t,x,y],x,x]+dif1*D[D[t,x,y],y,y]-D[uy C[t,x,y],y],d0<=x<=d1},{dif2*D[C[t,x,y],x,x]+dif2*D[C[t,x,y],y,y],d1<x<=d2}}];

cond={C[0,x,y]==0,Derivative[0,1,0][C][t,d0,y]==0,Derivative[0,1,0][C][t,d2,y]==0, Derivative[0,0,1][C][t,x,0]==0,(* here should be specified the other boundary conditions*)};

sol=NDSolve[{eqns,cond},C,{t,0,ts},{x,d0,d2},{y,0,h},MaxSteps->Infinity,Method->{"MethodOfLines","DifferentiateBoundaryConditions"->False}];

Where, dif1 and dif2 are the diffusion coefficients ate domains 1 and 2 respectively, uy is the convection velocity at domain 1, and ts a constant time value.
Could someone help me with this problem?

Did you see the monograph on MassTransportPDEComponent?

We have already reviewed the suggested module but it does not apply to the problem we have. There are no examples for two domains with different boundary conditions. If someone could give us some guidance we would be very grateful.

Adding a graphics of the domain would help understanding what you want to do.

Here is a way to do it, at least what I understand from your post.
The geometry:
h = 1;
d0 = 0; d1 = 1; d2 = 2;
regionMarker = <|"Material1" -> 1, "Material2" -> 2|>;
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{d0, 0}, {d1, 0}, {d2, 0}, {d2, h}, {d1, h}, {d0,
       h}}, "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 
        4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 1}, {2, 5}}]}];
bmesh["Wireframe"]


Set up variables, parameters and the PDE:
vars = {c[t, x, y], t, {x, y}};
pars = <|
   "DiffusionCoefficient" -> 
    Piecewise[{{1, ElementMarker == regionMarker["Material1"]}}, 2],
   "MassConvectionVelocity" -> {0, 
     Piecewise[{{uy, ElementMarker == regionMarker["Material1"]}}, 0]},
   uy -> 1/10
   |>;
pde = MassTransportPDEComponent[vars, pars] == 0;

Boundary and initial conditions:
bcs = MassConcentrationCondition[y == 0 && d1 <= x <= d2, vars, 
   pars, <|"MassConcentration" -> If[t <= 1/10, t, 1]|>];
ics = c[0, x, y] == 0;

Generate the mesh and make sure the region markers are present:
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{{(d0 + d1)/2, h/2}, 
      regionMarker["Material1"]}, {{(d1 + d2)/2, h/2}, 
      regionMarker["Material2"]}}];
mesh["MeshElementMarkerUnion"]
(* {1, 2} *)

Solve the PDE:
tEnd = 1;
solution = 
  NDSolveValue[{pde, bcs, ics}, 
   c, {t, 0, tEnd}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];

Create an animation:
frames = 
  Table[Plot3D[solution[t, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
    PlotRange -> {-$MachineEpsilon, 1}], {t, 0, tEnd, tEnd/10}];
ListAnimate[frames]


So, sure not exactly this example was in the MassTransport documentation, but the components are there and I would like to understand where you gave up and why?
